# Which models can I access from a controller in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

Suppose I have the classic Post model and I've created an Author model too.

I have some basic questions:

1. The Post object is automatically created whithin the PostsController?
2. In order to create an instance of Post whithin AuthorsController, is the only way with

`$this->Post = ClassRegistry::init('Post');`

Please notice that by doing " $this->Post " I assume the Post variable will be created in this line. Am I right ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Look into [model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html). If your associations are set up properly, you will be able to do

```
$this->Author->Post
```

to access the Post model from the Authorscontroller. If the model was not related but you still needed to access it, you could do so using the [$uses array](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#components-helpers-and-uses).

In terms of your first question, you are correct. All of your controllers extend Appcontroller which imports the default cake Controller class found in /lib/. You can see on line 376 in the [cakePHP controller file here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L376) that the model whose name is equal to the class name is loaded, after all of the models given in the $uses array are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

### All models in your uses array

You can access `$this->MmodelName` for all models declared in the [uses property](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses) - If this property is not declared it defaults to the model corresponding to the controller - i.e. `PostsContorller` -> `Post` model.

Models declared in `$uses` as created/instanciated on first reference - i.e. they are lazily created.